# django- jquery Datetime picker cannot save the form with date selected

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jquerydatetimepicker

In the html it displays a form, if I don't select any date from the datetime picker, the form could be submitted successfully.

But once I selected a date then I couldn't submit it. So I guess there might be something wrong in the date time format.

The Datetime picker works in the html, it shows dropdown list and I could also select it. Just I couldn't submit the form if I select a date.

**form html snippet for date time picker**

```
$(function() {
     $('.date-picker').datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: "yymm",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

                            function isDonePressed(){
                                return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
                            }
                            if (isDonePressed()){
                                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');

                                 $('.date-picker').focusout()//Added to remove focus from datepicker input box on selecting date
                            }
                        },
                        beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
                            inst.dpDiv.addClass('month_year_datepicker')

                            if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                                year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
                                month = datestr.substring(0, 2);
                                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
                                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                            }
                        }
                    })
        });
```

**models.py**

```
start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
end_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
widgets = {
        'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
    }
```

In the html, the date format is like 201010 (YYYYMM).

I was wondering if it was because the date format in html is not the same as in models, that's why I couldn't submit it.

Then please tell me how could I correct my models or forms if in this situation? The date format should be like in html (YYYYMM) 201003, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the form fields in your form class to accept your chosen date format:

```
start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%Y%m'), input_formats=['%Y%m']) 
end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%Y%m'), input_formats=['%Y%m'])
```

(This should work in both a regular `Form` and a `ModelForm`).