# django- concatenate(year,month)_range=[start_date,end_date] error

Tags: python, django, datetimepicker

In the SQL, there are Seperpated columns "year" and "month", now based on jquery datetime picker.  I can get the date entry from form in the format of yyyymm, such as 201012.

Question is how can I based on django form date entry range to filter the database.

The following is part of views.py, the queryset sentence is not correct. Please help correct.

```
 if form.is_valid():
     start_date=form.cleaned_data['start_date'] <---format is like 201012>
     end_date=form.cleaned_data['end_date']          

     queryset=Result.objects.filter(concatenate(year,month)_range=[start_date,end_date])  <!--filter in database)
```

Another question is:

since it is only YYYYMM, therefore if I defined start_date like below, it would not match the date format in html (YYYYMM). So how can I change in the models.py.

I have tried something like:

```
 start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,default=datetime.now().strftime("%m.%Y"))  but it is not correct.
```

**models.py** :

```
start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
end_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
start_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),required=False) 
end_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),required=False)
```

**Traceback after EDIT**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  159.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\xxxx\views.py" in get_queryset
  90.             start_date = datetime.strptime(form.cleaned_data['start_date'], '%Y%m') # format is like 201012

Exception Type: TypeError at /result_list/
Exception Value: must be string, not datetime.date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077799/django-filter-by-specified-month-and-year-in-date-range

Comment: I think  [Date Conveniences (Validation, Display, etc) for Partial Dates in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134526/date-conveniences-validation-display-etc-for-partial-dates-in-django) post can helps you.

Comment: Hi@danihp, thank you for the post. I have read it through this post, it didn't use concatenate method at all. In your opinion, if it is feasible to use concatenate method in my case?

Comment: @solarissmoke, I defined the start_date as models.DateField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%m.%Y")) with only year and month, but it reports error, can you tell me how to correct it please?

Comment: You are setting an string to a date field, may be the problem.  `DateField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%m.%Y")) `

Comment: Check my first comment. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps you need to take for this to work:

1. Configure your form field to accept dates in the "`YYYYMM`" format. In your Form class:

   ```
   start_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%Y%m'), input_formats=['%Y%m'], required=False) 
   end_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%Y%m'), input_formats=['%Y%m'], required=False)
   ```

This will allow Django to automatically parse your form data and save it correctly as a `datetime` object. Note that it will be stored as a full date (defaulting to the first of the month) - **you cannot use a `DateField` and ask it to store anything other than a full date**.

2. In your Model, set your defaults like so:

   ```
   start_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   ```

You have to store a full date in a `DateField`, so just let it default to the current date. This will still give correct results below (assuming the day of the month doesn't matter to you).

3. Your query logic would now be as follows:

   ```
   if form.is_valid():
       # Convert the form inputs into valid datetime objects
       start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
       end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']     

       # These are full dates... but we only want to compare month and year, so:

       queryset=Result.objects.filter(
           start_date__year__gte=start_date.year,
           start_date__month__gte=start_date.month, 
           end_date__year__lte=end_date.year,
           end_date__month__lte=end_date.month)
   ```

Comment: Hi@solarissmoke, can u please paste your answer to this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360631/django-jquery-datetime-picker-cannot-save-the-form-with-date-selected. I think your answer solves my this issue. In the queryset one, I cannot check now if it filters by date range, can you please answer my this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302186/django-why-after-redirecting-the-form-display-none, only after resolving this issue, I can test if it filters by date range. Thanks a lot~~~~.

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke,I got an error for "start_date = datetime.strptime(form.cleaned_data['start_date'], '%Y%m')" saying that "must be string, not datetime.date". I have uploaded the traceback for your reference.

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. The form inputs have already been converted to datetimes so you can use them directly. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Really thank you a lot,solarissmoke,  you save my day~~~I am thinking another issue now,because in database, the month is saved like "4","5"...without a leading 0, like "04","05". Therefore, when running the queryset code the month is like "04", which not matches the database. So in gte,lte function, there is no way to use similar thing like "concatenate"? is so then I can add a if judge then add 0 for those single digit month. Or another solution I thought is in sql, create a new column concatenating all year/month and  add a "1" for all dates. then it would match with the data picker result.